# TeXstudio is automatically compiling files that I don't know

Tags: pdf, compiling, texstudio

Whenever I am working on my paper or reading over some part that I wrote, TeXstudio will automatically run compile commands that will look like this:

```
Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "pDnAWy".tex

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "fbRqAJ".tex

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "NgUouV".tex

Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "HiKaRG".tex
```

The file names listed above don't exist. Once these commands finish, TeXstudio will open my PDF-Viewer for about half a second on the confidentiality clause section of my thesis and close again automatically. This makes it very difficult to read and write without sudden interruptions. I encountered this TeXstudio 2.12.22 on both Ubuntu 19.10 and Windows 7.
It doesn't happen with other Tex-Editors. It usually starts happening after some time and stops again after a while.

Is this a normal behavior? If yes, can I deactivate it somewhere?